# Слежение камеры при смерти игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Камера следит за игроком, но когда он умирает, то естественно она его теряет и возникает ошибка, но я, честно говоря, вообще не понимаю, как в момент потери игрока просто остановить камеру. Помогите пожалуйста)

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float delta = 0.003f;
    private float speed = 0.01f;
    public Transform Camera;
    public Transform Player;

    private void Update()

    { 
        var cameraPosition = Camera.position;
        cameraPosition.x = Mathf.Lerp(cameraPosition.x, Player.position.x, speed);
        cameraPosition.y = Mathf.Lerp(cameraPosition.y, Player.position.y, speed)+ delta;
        Camera.position = cameraPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: `возникает ошибка` надо догадаться, какая?

Comment: Ошибка возникает вероятно потому, что вы пишете логику слежения камеры за игроком в функции Update. Вам следует выполнять этот код при каких-либо событиях, а не каждый фрейм :)
Из-за того, что камера перемещается каждый фрейм, после смерти игрока - объект игрок, я так понимаю, удаляется и камера имеет нулевой указатель, который передается как 2 параметр функции Lerp.

Comment: Я предлагаю вам не писать логику слежения камеры за игроков в Update, но если вы уже решили делать так, то вам нужна проверка на то, жив ли игрок. Это замедлит производительность, потому что, повторюсь, функция Update вызывается каждый фрейм.

Answer (score 0):

Если камера является дочерним объектом вашего игрока, то когда игрок умирает, просто делаем:

```
camera.parent = null;
```